# Dexterity and TinyMCE 1.3 on Plone 4.1.6

Tags: tinymce, plone, dexterity

Versions:

- Plone 4.1.6
- TinyMCE 1.3.5
- plone.app.dexterity 1.2.1
- plone.dexterity 1.1.2

I'm upgrading TinyMCE on a site to fix some bugs we were seeing with the older version. But after upgrading to 1.3.5, editing custom dexterity types is throwing this error:

```
    URL: file:/Users/chrissy/.buildout/eggs/Products.TinyMCE-1.3.5-py2.6.egg/Products/TinyMCE/skins/tinymce/tinymce_wysiwyg_support.pt
Line 6, Column 2
Expression: <PythonExpr configuration_method(field=field)>
Names:

{'args': (),
 'context': <Container at /a4a/archives/2012>,
 'default': <object object at 0x107e61ca0>,
 'loop': {},
 'nothing': None,
 'options': {},
 'repeat': {},
 'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:51117/a4a/archives/2012/++add++a4a.archives.historyitem>,
 'template': <zope.browserpage.viewpagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x10e662e50>,
 'view': <RichTextWidget 'form.widgets.text'>,
 'views': <zope.browserpage.viewpagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x110605cd0>}

Module Products.PageTemplates.ZRPythonExpr, line 48, in __call__
__traceback_info__: configuration_method(field=field)
Module PythonExpr, line 1, in <expression>
Module Products.TinyMCE.browser.browser, line 127, in jsonConfiguration
Module Products.TinyMCE.utility, line 957, in getConfiguration
Module Products.CMFPlone.browser.ploneview, line 309, in bodyClass
Module plone.app.layout.globals.layout, line 133, in bodyClass

AttributeError: 'View' object has no attribute 'getId'
```

The custom types are using `plone.app.textfield.RichText`. Default types (using Archetypes) work fine.

I am using the newest Dexterity that will work on this version of Plone, but is there a different version of TinyMCE that I could use that wouldn't cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use branch 1.3 of Products.TinyMCE on Plone 4.1 (neither Plone 4.2) because of a hard dependency with `plone.app.layout >=2.3.7` introduced at some point; you're stuck with branch 1.2.

Comment: Thanks, Hector. Unfortunately this version does not include the fix I needed.

Comment: the problem was [this commit](https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/commit/fe5392343dec32eace38ba406da4c5c02518a9f0); you could try up to release 1.3.5.